# Razor: how to escape dot character next to a variable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a `size` variable which I need to insert in HTML, like this:

```
<img src="/Content/img/icons/coins_@size.png" />
```

to get something like this:

```
<img src="/Content/img/icons/coins_16.png" />
```

But ASP.NET thinks that `png` is a method of `size`. Is there a way to escape the dot coming after the variable?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Add parentheses:

```
<img src="/Content/img/icons/coins_@(size).png" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Just had to do something very similar earlier today. This should work for you:

```
<img src="/Content/img/icons/coins_@(size).png" />
```